# Searching inside of sections within a listview

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm currently trying to extend an example that I found on http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/.

I first extended this by creating an EditText to function as my search bar and then followed a few tutorials to implement the Filter function. What I'm trying to do is when a user inputs a text, if the section has matching text, return the section and all its sub-items. If a sub-item is searched return its section and the sub-item matching the constraint. My functions work when there is no sections however it does not work at all with the sections.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

main_list.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.myapplication">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxWidth="100dp"
    android:minWidth="300dp"
    android:singleLine="true"/>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/search_text"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I then modified a bit of the main activity so that I can implement the search bar.

ListSample.java

```
public class ListSample extends Activity {

SeparatedListAdapter adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_list);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    EditText inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_text);

    List<String> america = new ArrayList<>();
    america.add("Chicago");
    america.add("Washington");
    List<String> australia = new ArrayList<>();
    australia.add("Sydney");
    australia.add("Melbourne");
    australia.add("Perth");
    List<String> combined = new ArrayList<>();
    combined.addAll(america);
    combined.addAll(australia);


    // create our list and custom adapter
    adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this, combined);
    adapter.addSection("America", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, america));

    adapter.addSection("Australia", new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.list_item, australia));


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}

}
```

Filter fucntions

```
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if(filter == null){
        filter = new dataFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}
private class dataFilter extends Filter{
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        ArrayList<String> filterList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0){

            for(int i =0; i < originalDataFilterList.size(); i++){
                if(originalDataFilterList.get(i).toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                    filterList.add(originalDataFilterList.get(i));

                }

            }

            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;

        } else {
            results.count = originalDataFilterList.size();
            results.values = originalDataFilterList;
        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results){
        originalData = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing a part of your code on filters, e.g. creation of `originalDataFilterList` and how `originalData` is used.

Comment: @headuck sorry I was only highlighting the parts that I changed, http://paste.ofcode.org/e5gXT4D5uVXYg62adAmUiT

here is the full code for that class

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your filter result is stored in the `originalData` array without sub-section information.  The code did not modify the `headers` adapter and `sections` map which are stored separately in the `SeparatedListAdapter`, and thus no change would occur when you change the filter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Instead of creating and passing the `combined` list to the `SeparatedListAdapter`, and use this 'flat' list for filtering, you may need to iterate on the `sections` map and its adapters during the filtering, store the filtering results, and then the `getItem()`, `getCount()`, `getViewTypeCount()`, `getItemViewType()`, `isEnabled()`, `getView()` and `getItemId()` methods need to be rewritten to take into account the result.

There are many ways to implement this. For example, to avoid re-creating the `sections` and `headers` arrays each time your filter changes, you can calculate and store a mapping of list view `position` to the appropriate header and subitem (by storing the offset for headers / adapter and position for subitems), for application by methods such as `getItem()` accordingly.  You also need to calculate the total count (for retrieval by `getCount()`).